# Nosys.specs missing when building RPi Pico LittleFS on M1 macOS

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

Recently I am trying to use RPi Pico to program ice40 FPGA. I have thought I could save the bin file of FPGA to the Flash RAM of RPi Pico and then read it and program the FPGA using it. However I couldn't ve find much info on storing files on RPi Pico, so I tried using LittleFS (https://github.com/lurk101/pico-littlefs). I have downloaded it, however I can't really build it (using make) , it gives me this error:

```
[1%] Linking ASM executable bs2_default.elf
arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot read spec file 'nosys.specs': No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/bs2_default.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Nonetheless, if I try to build some example program using pico-sdk it goes without an issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-feedback/issues/355) which helped me, basically it just needed another version of arm gcc.